# GetModuleHandle(NULL) on Linux

Tags: linux

Is there a way to `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` on Linux to be able to pass that handle into dlsym 3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) for `dlopen`(3) states:

> The function `dlopen()` loads the dynamic library file named by the
>   null-terminated string `filename` and returns an opaque "handle" for the
>   dynamic library. If `filename` is `NULL`, then the returned handle is for
>   the main program.

Therefore, you can use the value returned by `dlopen(NULL)` as the `handle` argument to `dlsym()`.

Answer (score 2):

`dlopen(NULL)` will give you a handle for the executable.